# TeamCity export CoverageReport.xml to a predefined directory

Tags: teamcity

I am trying out TeamCity for our CI.
We have a build step running NUnit for unit test and dotCover for code coverage. The process went through fine, but im just wondering if it is possible to export the Build Log and the dotCover's CoverageReport.xml to a predefined directory on the local machine.

or maybe even export all the artifacts and reports used in the build to a local folder.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a build step ( command line ) that will copy over the reports that you need to the desired location locally.

Comment: thanks, im examining the temp folder that the coverage xml gets exported by default. the folder look like this "teamcity8116912053787299497ncover" is there a pattern to it? the number in between, is it possible to get it from the predefined properties? thansk

Comment: Tried it, but the command line build step (place at the very last step) actually runs before nunit and dotcover's finish their processing thou. any thought?